# javascript font-resizer not working in IE8 or IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to create a site-wide font resizer, but most of the implementations seem to want me to target elements by id or class, instead of site-wide.

I'm trying to do accomplish my task by setting up my pages starting with this CSS:

- html = 83%
- body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,p,blockquote,th,td,etc...  = 1em

Then, I have some jquery that grabs the currently applied font-size, increases it and re-applies it.

But it's not working in IE8 or IE7. (shocker)

```
var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.05;
$("html").css('cssText', 'font-size: ' + newFontSize + 'px !important');
```

If I console.log out the values, it's computing fine in those browsers, but there seems to be something about relative font sizing in those browsers.  I also tried resetting everything to 100%, instead of 1em, but that didn't work, either.

Example [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/scott_in_ct/YyWNn/) (but this site doesn't work in ie8 or below.....)

Comment: have you tried adding the 'em' or 'px' at the end of it? `font-size:1.05` or `font-size:12` doesnt mean anything explicitly, and u might just be getting the benefit of the doubt from new browsers

Comment: it is important to set `line-height` everytime just after `font-size: [n]em` and `font-size: [n]%`, fixed fontsizes go in `px`. this should work in IE too. as i'm right even with some layout breaks could be it works here.. http://archaos.de

Comment: I tried that (updated example).  That's not it.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing it on `html` element and not `body`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work in IE8 & IE7, so I changed my code to apply a class to the html object (body would work, too).  Then, in the IE8 & IE7 css files, I have styles that are listening for those classes and adjust their sizes, accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the size without any unit. Add `px` to the size:

```
$('html').css('font-size', newFontSize + 'px');
```

---

Side note: the `parseFloat` function doesn't take any radix parameter:

```
var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize);
```

Comment: oops, my code wasn't the actual code i used.  I AM using the unit in my code.  I updated my example.